# Fetching data from Kinvey backend

Tags: android, loaddata, kinvey

I am using kinvey as my backend where I have a collection and would like to fetch data using appData.get.  I have tried using the code below but it doesnt work. Could someone please tell me whats wrong with it.

```
package com.example.kinvey;

import com.kinvey.android.AsyncAppData;
import com.kinvey.android.callback.KinveyListCallback;
import com.kinvey.java.core.KinveyClientCallback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Entity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActionData extends Activity{

//protected static final String TAG = "LOG:";
public static final String TAG = "ActionData";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void onLoadClick(View view) {

    AsyncAppData<Entity> myevents = MainActivity.mKinveyClient.appData("events",Entity.class);
    myevents.get(new KinveyListCallback<Entity>()     {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Entity[] result) { 
        Log.v(TAG, "received "+ result.length + " events");
      }
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable error)  { 
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to fetch all", error);
      }
    });     
}
```

And this is my Entity class.

```
package com.example.kinvey;

import com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;
import com.kinvey.java.model.KinveyMetaData;

public class Entity extends GenericJson{

@Key("_id")
private String id; 

@Key("_class")
private String _class;

@Key("author")
private String author;

@Key("relatedObj")
private String relatedObj;

@Key("relatedObjName")
private String relatedObjName;

@Key("type")
private String type;

@Key("_kmd")
private KinveyMetaData meta; 

@Key("_acl")
private KinveyMetaData.AccessControlList acl; 

public Entity(){}  

public String getActionId() {
    return id;
}

public void setActionId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getclass() {
    return _class;
}

public void setclass(String _class) {
    this._class = _class;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getRelatedObj() {
    return relatedObj;
}

public void setRelatedObj(String relatedObj) {
    this.relatedObj = relatedObj;
}

public String getRelatedObjName() {
    return relatedObjName;
}

public void setRelatedObjName(String relatedObjName) {
    this.relatedObjName = relatedObjName;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm an engineer at Kinvey and have been working on the Android library.  That looks right so far!  Does `received 0 events` get logged or do you not see anything at all?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, the Logcat shows `code` recieved 0 events. Should it be like this?

Comment: In my code, I have the string "events". I am not sure it is the right thing to put there. What exactly should be in the string parameter of kinveyClient.appData() method? I also realized that on the implemented method "public void on success()" I tried to do result.getRelatedObjName() but it brings an error. getRelatedObjName() is a method in class Entity. What could be the problem?

Comment: visit: console.kinvey.com/addons/datastore and login, that will show your data-- in this case, `events` is a "collection", and I am assuming it is empty!  Try calling `AppData.save(...)` to create a new entity (or add one in the browser, at the above link).  Let me know if that makes sense!